# Detecting Bangla character using pytesseract

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I am trying to detect bangla character from image using python, so i decided to use **pytesseract**. For this purpose i have used below code:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter

im = Image.open("input.png") # the second one
im = im.filter(ImageFilter.MedianFilter())
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im)
im = enhancer.enhance(2)
im = im.convert('1')
im.save('temp2.png')
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('temp2.png'),lang="ben")
print text
```

The problem is that if i gave a image of english character is detects. But when i am writing `lang="ben"` and detecting from image of bengali characters my code is running for endless time or like forever.

**P.S:** I have downloaded bengali language train data to tessdata folder and i am trying to run it in **PyCharm**.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

[sample of input.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkkW7.jpg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I added `Bangla(india)` language to Windows. Downloaded `ben.traineddata` to `TESSDATA_PREFIX` which equals to `C:\Program Files\Tesseract 4.0.0\tessdata` in my PC. Then run,

`> tesseract -l ben bangla.jpg bangla_out`

in command prompt and got the result below in 2 seconds.  The result looks fine even I don't understand the language.

[image]

Have you tried to run tesseract in command prompt to verify if it works for `-l ben`?

> **EDIT:**
>
> Used **Spyder**, similar to PyCharm, which comes with Anaconda to test
>   it. Modified your code to call Tesseract as below.
>
> ```
> pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:/Program Files/Tesseract 4.0.0/tesseract.exe"
> ```
>
> Test Code in Spyder:
>
> ```
> import pytesseract
> from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter
> import os
>
> im = Image.open("bangla.jpg") # the second one
> im = im.filter(ImageFilter.MedianFilter())
> enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im)
> im = enhancer.enhance(2)
> im = im.convert('1')
> im.save("bangla_pp.jpg")
>
> pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:/Program Files/Tesseract 4.0.0/tesseract.exe"
> text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("bangla_pp.jpg"),lang="ben")
> print text
> ```
>
> It works and produced result below on the processed image. Apparently, the OCR result of the processed image is not as good as the original one.
>
> Result from the processed bangla_pp.jpg:
>
> ```
>    প্রত্যাবর্তনকারীরা
>    তাঁদের দেশে গিয়ে
>
>    -~~-<~~~~--
>
>    প্রত্যাবর্তন-পরবর্তী
>    আর্থিক সহায়তা
>     = পাবেন তার
> ```
>
> Result from original image, directly feed to Tesseract.
>
> Code:
>
> ```
> from PIL import Image    
> import pytesseract as tess
>
> print tess.image_to_string(Image.open('bangla.jpg'), lang='ben')
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> প্রত্যাবর্তনকারীরা
> তাঁদের দেশে গিয়ে
>
> প্রত্যাবর্তন-পরবর্তী
> আর্থিক সহায়তা
> পাবেন তার
> ```

Comment: I have tried it in command prompt it works. But the above code is written in **pycharm**. In **pycharm**, it runs for unlimited time.

Comment: @pial see the EDIT above.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed some fonts in windows from here

https://www.omicronlab.com/bangla-fonts.html

After that, it worked perfectly fine for me in Pycharm.